# ¿Como evitar que muestre error al utilizar el metodo $_REQUEST en php?

Tags: php

Bueno explico , al cargar mi pagina.php desde un servidor local me muestra el siguiente error: Undefined index: var_entrada ...line 17.Este es el codigo:

```
 <form action="pagina.php">
    <p><input type="text" name="var_entrada" ></p>
    <input type="submit" value="enviar">
 </form>

 <?php 
        $var1 = 0;
        $cont = 0;
        $suma = 0;

        $var1 = $_REQUEST['var_entrada'];

        while($cont <= $var1){
            $suma += $cont;
            $cont ++;
        }
        echo "Numero de entrada: ".$var1."<br>";
        echo "Suma: ".$suma;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con isset se valida que exista ese dato o variable, en este caso el dato que se envió en el request:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['var_entrada'])) {
    $var1 = 0;
    $cont = 0;
    $suma = 0;

    $var1 = $_REQUEST['var_entrada'];

    while($cont <= $var1){
        $suma += $cont;
        $cont ++;
    }
    echo "Numero de entrada: ".$var1."<br>";
    echo "Suma: ".$suma;
}
```